# ConvertTo-SecureString run without key on different user account, is there a way (with proper credentials) to get this working from a different user?

Tags: powershell, encryption

I have a VM that I have full access to with access to all accounts. My question below is all run on the **same** machine, just under different user accounts.

If I logon with `domain\user1` and run the following PowerShell to generate a string of a `SecureString`:

```
$SecurePassword = "ThisIsATest" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$RawSecureString = $SecurePassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString

Write-Host $RawSecureString
```

So the output is below:

> `$RawSecureString = "01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb0100000014c54a4678625849adf32615ece5d33f000000000200000000001066000000010000200000007ece54f23781b598d0341c2380e678bc6286222186717e612e0f095b3edc4137000000000e80000000020000200000006b68df76dbc98fcd35943be7818c80ed502ec49d0ae06deeec183367ea19e10d200000002087d6178d6a67165d41ed172e11eae6bf7d648a59d25c01dd573baaad985bb040000000adc87d779c7de9d1565bcb834e50214e982c133c3558111138a2e1964b599d1bcb7b4583ff18d314f7bc6a0549bf03342a49ba2456cc13df60585ca36125ae37"`

With `domain\user1` I run the following:

```
$SecureString = $RawSecureString | ConvertTo-SecureString
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($SecureString))
```

and the output is `ThisIsATest`, which is good.

If I logon as `domain\user2` and run the following:

```
$RawSecureString = "01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb0100000014c54a4678625849adf32615ece5d33f000000000200000000001066000000010000200000007ece54f23781b598d0341c2380e678bc6286222186717e612e0f095b3edc4137000000000e80000000020000200000006b68df76dbc98fcd35943be7818c80ed502ec49d0ae06deeec183367ea19e10d200000002087d6178d6a67165d41ed172e11eae6bf7d648a59d25c01dd573baaad985bb040000000adc87d779c7de9d1565bcb834e50214e982c133c3558111138a2e1964b599d1bcb7b4583ff18d314f7bc6a0549bf03342a49ba2456cc13df60585ca36125ae37"
$SecureString = $RawSecureString | ConvertTo-SecureString
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($SecureString))
```

I get `Key not valid for use in specified state.`, because it's a different user.

Since there is no key provided during encryption by `user1`, my question is, if I have access to both logon accounts, is there a way from `user2` to decrypt this secure string?

The reason is I have many VM's where keys were stored in the registry as the local administer account and most of what I'm doing is from a remote domain account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but you will have to recreate the SecureStrings.

The strings encrypted by `ConvertTo-SecureString` can only be de-crypted by the same computer and user account that encrypted them by default.

You can use work around this with the `-Key` parameter. [From the helpful folks at PDQ](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/).

You create an AES key like so:

```
$KeyFile = "C:\AES.key"
$Key = New-Object Byte[] 16   # You can use 16 (128-bit), 24 (192-bit), or 32 (256-bit) for AES
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($Key)
$Key | Out-File $KeyFile
```

Create the new SecureString object:

```
$PasswordFile = "C:\Password.txt"
$KeyFile = "C:\AES.key"
$Key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$Password = "P@ssword1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $Key | Out-File $PasswordFile
```

Creating PSCredential object on another computer or user:

```
$User = "MyUserName"
$PasswordFile = "C:\Password.txt"
$KeyFile = "C:\AES.key"
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$MyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)
```

Anyone who gets the `AES.key` file will be able to decrypt the SecureString object so be mindful can access it!

Comment: The strings I need exist on these machines in the registry already. I believe this method is the correct way to do it if I was starting from scratch. The VMs are from Microsoft, so I can't really get them to fix their mistake easily, so I'm trying to work around.

Comment: So the strings in the registry are there from the start and they're secure strings? If so, unless you decypt them with the account that encrypted them there isn't anything I know of that you can do from any other account.

Comment: That's sort of where I arrived at as well. I'm thinking I could do some powershell remote execution as the local admin user then wrap everything up in a way to replace it in place. I was hoping you could get a "user key" or something to impersonate the user.