# Using credentials in powershell

Tags: powershell, rights

I want my script to be executed by another user

```
# $root contains \\srv\folder

$create_folders_button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$create_folders_button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,75)
$create_folders_button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$create_folders_button.Text = 'Utwórz katalogi'
$create_folders_button.add_Click({
    $username = "domain\user"

    $password = Get-Content "$root\pwd.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
    
    $credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,$password)
    
    Start-Process powershell -argument "$root\make_project_folder_with_subfolders.ps1" -Credential ($credentials)
    # $form_start.close()
})
$form_start.Controls.Add($create_folders_button)
```

Basically I know why it's not working but i don't know how to fix it.

The issue is `$password` have no data stored. Password was exported to txt file using this command:

`(Get-Credential).Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File $filepath`

File is stored on share and all users have rx rights.

```
FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : Wszyscy
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None
```

Comment: `ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force`

Comment: Note that your saved SecureString will be encrypted on a per-user,per-computer basis, so only the original user/computer combination will be able to retrieve and use it properly.  See here for details of a way around this: [ConvertTo-SecureString run without key on different user account...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006674/convertto-securestring-run-without-key-on-different-user-account-is-there-a-way)

Comment: Thank you @boxdog .
I didn't know that.
I had theory that this was an issue here.